# ¿Cómo hacer que, al llenar un campo de texto en un formulario, al presionar la tecla enter, se haga una consulta a la base de datos en php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

estoy tratando de hacer un formulario en html y php, realmente soy nuevo en esto, tengo muy pocos conocimientos en php y javascript, e intento hacer dicho formulario con dos campos de tipo Text y dos de tipo Select, los campos de texto, específicamente en lo que estoy haciendo, uno es donde irá contraseña y otro donde irá el usuario, en uno de los select irá empresa y en el otro, sucursal. Lo que exactamente necesito es que, en el campo de texto de contraseña, se escriba justo eso, la contraseña y que al presionar la tecla enter, se haga una consulta a la base de datos y si esa contraseña existe, que muestre en el resto de campos los datos que corresponden, es decir, que en el campo de texto de usuario no haya nada, ni en las opciones de los select de empresa y sucursal, y que se llenen automáticamente al consultar en la base de datos si existen los datos que se envió con la tecla enter desde el text de contraseña.

Por poner un ejemplo más específico, supongamos que en el text de contraseña escribo la contraseña "X", y que esta contraseña está registrada en una fila de la base de datos y tiene un id=1, y que en la misma fila en sus campos correspondientes tiene usuario "5", empresa "A", y sucursal "2". ¿cómo hacer para que, como mencioné anteriormente al dar enter en el text de contraseña se haga consulta a la base de datos si esa contraseña tiene un id y el resto de datos, y que los muestre cada uno en su campo correspondiente? es decir, que muestre siempre en el text la contraseña "X", pero que ahora el otro text de usuario y los selct no estén vacíos, si no que, estén llenos con los datos que les corresponden, y que ya al estar llenos todos los campos, que con el botón submit se envíen estos datos a la base de datos, cada uno, en su campo correspondiente dentro de la misma.

(Actualmente este codigo lo que hace es enviar datos a la base de datos, es decir, que se llenan todos los datos del formulario y con el submit se envían, pero ahora no es eso lo que quiero, si no que, únicamente se pueda escribir en el text de contraseña, que el de usuario esté deshabilitado y que los select no contengan nada, y que desde el campo de texto de contraseña se haga la consulta para que, como mencioné anteriormente se llenen el resto de campos automáticamente si esa contraseña está registrada en la base de datos, y que se envíe todo con el submit, hasta que todos los campos estén llenos)

Aclaro algo: Para lo que realmente necesito llenarlos en automático es para enviarlos todos a otra tabla en la base de datos, lo que realmente quiero hacer es traer cada dato de cada campo de tablas diferentes, es decir, el usuario de una tabla, la empresa de otra tabla, y así sucesivamente pero que todos correspondan al mismo id de la contraseña que se envió, y que cada dato se coloque en el campo que le corresponde dentro del formulario, y luego ya enviar todos los datos del formulario a otra tabla.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Adjunto mi código html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inicio30.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>Gestión 2022</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include ("ingresar.php");
    ?>
<div class="divarriba">
       

       <h5>SDIG</h5>
       <h6>Gestión</h6>

       <div class="icon2 icon-key"></div>

       <h1>Gestión Web</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="esquina"></div>


    
    <table class="ingresardatos">
        <tr>
    <form method="post">
        
    <td><h2 class="contraseña">Contraseña:</h2></td>
            <td class="td"><input class="boxcontraseña" id="contraseña" type="text" name="contraseña" autocomplete="off"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <td><h2 class="usuario">Usuario:</h2></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="boxusuario" id="usuario" name="usuario"></td>
        </tr>
    
    <tr>
            <td><h2 class="empresa">Empresa:</h2></td>
            <td><select name="empresa" id="empresa" style="width:98%; height:calc(1.2em + 1.2vw);" >

                <option>A</option>
                
                <option>B</option>
                
                <option>C</option>
                
                </select></td>
        </tr>

        
        <tr>
            <td><h2 class="sucursal">Sucursal:</h2></td>
            <td><select name="sucursal" id="sucursal" style="width:98%; height:calc(1.2em + 1.2vw);" >

                <option>A</option>
                
                <option>B</option>
                
                <option>C</option>
                
                </select></td></td>
        </tr>
        
    </table>




<div class="divabajo">

<table class="botonesabajo">
<tr>
<td><label style="color:green; background: white; font-size: calc(1em + 1vw); border-radius: 45%; width: 20%;"><input type="submit" id="register" class="btingresar" value="Ingresar" name="register"></td>
<td><button class="btcancelar"><label style="color:white; font-size: calc(1em + 1vw);"></label> Cancelar</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


</div>




</body>
</html>
```

y el código php:

```
<?php 



if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    if (strlen($_POST['contraseña']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['usuario']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['empresa']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['sucursal']) >= 1) {
        $contraseña = trim($_POST['contraseña']);
        $usuario = trim($_POST['usuario']);
        $empresa = trim($_POST['empresa']);
        $sucursal = trim($_POST['sucursal']);
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO clientes(contraseña, usuario, empresa, sucursal) VALUES ('$contraseña', '$usuario', '$empresa', '$sucursal')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
        if ($resultado) {
            ?> 
            <h3 class="ok">Has ingresado correctamente</h3>
           <?php
        } else {
            ?> 
            <h3 class="bad">¡Ups ha ocurrido un error!</h3>
           <?php
        }
    }   else {
            ?> 
            <h3 class="bad">¡Por favor complete los campos!</h3>
           <?php
    }
}

include("conexbd.php");
?>
```

Comment: Creo que entendí lo que quieres y hay muchas formas de hacerlo, para ello se puede utilizar funciones js y Ajax, lo que no entiendo para que quieres que se llenen los datos en automático y luego enviarlos nuevamente, si se supone que esos datos los estas ya consultando de una tabla en tu BD, por otro lado, que haz intentado?.

Comment: Para lo que realmente necesito llenarlos en automático es para enviarlos todos a otra tabla en la base de datos,  lo que realmente quiero hacer es traer cada dato de cada campo de tablas diferentes, es decir, el usuario de una tabla, la empresa de otra tabla, y así sucesivamente pero que todos correspondan al mismo id de la contraseña que se envió, y que cada dato se coloque en el campo que le corresponde dentro del formulario, y luego ya enviar todos los datos del formulario a otra tabla.